# Using Web::Scraper to pull HTML tags with a data marker

Tags: perl, web-scraping

The purpose of this code is to parse an HTML file and return content that is wrapped with tags that have the `data-reader` attribute.

This works as desired, but I would also like to get the associated HTML tag, but I don't know how to have it returned in the scrape data.

Is this possible?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;

use Web::Scraper;

my $html = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $s = scraper {
  process '*', 'links[]' => '@data-reader';
  process '*', 'content[]' => 'text';
};

my $res = $s->scrape($html);

for my $i (0 .. @{ $res->{links} } ) {
  if ($res->{links}[$i]) {
    print "<??>$res->{content}[$i]</??>\n";
  }
}
exit;

__DATA__
<h1 data-reader="on">Hello <em>world</em></h1>
<h2>This is subheading</h2>
<h3 style="color:#000;" data-reader="on" class="phead">Paragraph Heading</h3>
```

Output:

```
<??>Hello world</??>
<??>Paragraph Heading</??>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Web::Scraper;
use HTML::Entities;

my $html = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $s = scraper {
    process '[data-reader]', 'list[]' => {
        tag     => sub { $_->tag },
        content => 'TEXT',
    };
    result 'list';
};

my $results = $s->scrape($html);

for my $part (@$results) {
    print "<$part->{tag}>" . encode_entities($part->{content}) . "</$part->{tag}>\n";
}

__DATA__
<h1 data-reader="on">Hello <em>world</em></h1>
<h2>This is subheading</h2>
<h3 style="color:#000;" data-reader="on" class="phead">Paragraph Heading</h3>
```

Output:

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<h3>Paragraph Heading</h3>
```

The ability to pass a raw subroutine as the extractor specification seems to be undocumented, but

1. the [Web::Scraper documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MIYAGAWA/Web-Scraper-0.38/lib/Web/Scraper.pm) is spotty in general, and
2. it's used in [at least one example](https://metacpan.org/source/MIYAGAWA/Web-Scraper-0.38/eg/dave-trailer-HD.pl#L17),

so I don't feel too bad about using it.

I'm re-encoding `$part->{content}` as HTML to avoid issues in case someone does e.g.

```html
<div data-reader="on">&lt;script&gt;alert(42)&lt;/script&gt;</div>
```

If you were to just print `$part->{content}`, it would give you `<script>alert(42)</script>`, which is probably not what you want.

---

In detail:

```
my $s = scraper {
    process '[data-reader]', 'list[]' => {
        tag     => sub { $_->tag },
        content => 'TEXT',
    };
    result 'list';
};
```

`scraper` takes a block of code and wraps it in an object. Every time the `scrape` method of this object is called, the block of code is run. In theory you can do anything you want there, but the only sensible things are calls to `process` and `result`.

`process` takes three (or more) arguments. The first argument is a CSS (or XPath if it starts with `//` or `id(`) selector. In this case (`[data-reader]`) we're selecting all elements that have a `data-reader` attribute.

The remaining arguments are key/value pairs. `scraper` provides an implicit context (also known as "stash"), which is simply a hash were results are placed. The "key" argument specifies under which hash key the results of the extraction should be placed. If the "key" argument ends with `[]`, it is stripped and the value is not a single result, but a reference to an array of results.

Here we use `list[]` as the "key" argument, which means that we're accumulating results under the `list` key of the stash.

The "value" argument specifies what value we want to store under our key. Possible values include `TEXT` (the text value of a node) and `@foo` (the value of the `foo` attribute of the element in question).

Here we're using a hash reference, which means we want to construct a nested subhash. Each key/value pair of our hash is interpreted as described above. We get entries for `tag` (containing the tag name as returned by [the `tag` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Element#tag)) and `content` (containing the text value of our element).

The effect is as if `scrape` contained the following loop:

```
my %stash;
for my $node (@found_nodes) {
    push @{$stash{list}}, {
        tag     => $node->tag,
        content => get_plain_text_somehow($node),
    };
}
```

Normally `scrape` returns the stash, but if the scrape block contains `result` (which must be the last statement in the block), you can make it return just a single key (or if you pass multiple strings to `result`, a hash containing just a subset of keys). That is, because of `result 'list'`, instead of

```
return \%stash;
```

we effectively get

```
return $stash{list};
```

Comment: I googled my hiney off before resorting to posting a question. The documentation (such that it was) melted my brain. I don't totally understand the requirements of the `scraper` call, and I understand your code even less. But it certainly does _exactly_ what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @TimothyB. I added some details about what the code does (hope it helps). Also, feel free to [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the extra explanation. I'd never heard of a stash before. Using Data::Dumper I was able glean without true understanding of how to access the information that was returned. This was very helpful!